# An example of a differentiable manifold class $C^k$ but not class $C^{k +1} $

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, differential-topology

I'm looking for an example of a differentiable manifold of  class $C^k$ but not class $C^{k +1}.$
I found an exercise in Hirsh's book, which suggests that the graph of $f (x) = |x|^{\lambda}$, where $k<\lambda<k+1$
is a differentiable manifold of  class $C^k$ but not class $C^{k+1}$.
I initially  thought the atlas given by the graph coordinates , but obviously does not work.

**My problem**:what kind of differentiable structure I need for the graph of $ f $ is a differentiable  manifold of class $C^k$ but not $C^{k +1}$

Comment: There is a trivial but perhaps not very illuminating answer to this question: Start with any $C^\infty$ manifold. Now to the atlas of charts on this manifold you add all the charts that are $C^k$ compatible with all the given charts of the original manifold. You now have a $C^k$ manifold (obviously), that is not $C^{k+1}$ (and to prove the latter, you only need to find a single $C^k$ chart that is not $C^{k+1}$ compatible with the original structure).